# How to group my LINQ query so that I get the desired result?

Tags: vb.net, linq, grouping

I have a few tables which logically form a forest:

- `tblFilterSum` has `SumID` as its key and any such elements are roots in the forest
- `tblFilterProdsInSum` is a table which represents a many-to-many relation between `tblFilterSum` and `tblFilterProd` via `SumID` and `ProdID`
- `tblFilterProd` has `ProdID` as its key
- `tblFilterElementsInProd` is a many-to-many relation between `tblFilterProd` and `tblFilterElement` via `ProdID` and `ElementID`
- `tblFilterElement` represents the set of leaf nodes

Logical context:

We are working with logical filter expressions. `tblFilterElement` is an atomic logical expression. Many `tblFilterElement` item can be linked to a `tblFilterProd` via `tblFilterElementsInProd`. `tblFilterProd` represents a composite logical expression where the `tblFilterElement` items are evaluated and separated with `AND`. `tblFilterSum` represents a composite logical expression where `tblFilterProd` elements are evaluated and separated by `OR`. I would like to gather a set of `tblFilterSum` items based on a set of `sumIDs`, which is a `List(Of Integer)` and I would like to have a result of

```
Dim result As List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, List(Of Tuple(Integer, List(Of TblFilterElement)))))
```

where each result represents a `tblFilterSum`, `item1` will be the `SumID` of `tblFilterSum`, `item2` will be a `List` where each element represents a `TblFilterProd` in the `TblFilterSum` and of each `TblFilterProd`, `item1` will be the `ProdID` and `item2` will be a `List` containing all the `TblFilterElement` items in the prod.

This is my current code:

```
        Dim elements = (From filterSum In BOs.GeneralBO.GetDataContext.GetTable(Of TblFilterSum)
                        Join filterProdInSum In BOs.GeneralBO.GetDataContext.GetTable(Of TblFilterProdsInSum)
                        On filterSum.SumID Equals filterProdInSum.SumID
                        Join filterProd In BOs.GeneralBO.GetDataContext.GetTable(Of TblFilterProd)
                        On filterProdInSum.ProdID Equals filterProd.ProdID
                        Join filterElementInProd In BOs.GeneralBO.GetDataContext.GetTable(Of TblFilterElementsInProd)
                        On filterProd.ProdID Equals filterElementInProd.ProdID
                        Join filterElement In BOs.GeneralBO.GetDataContext.GetTable(Of TblFilterElement)
                        On filterElementInProd.ElementID Equals filterElement.ElementID
                        Where sumIDs.Contains(filterSum.SumID))
```

which is great and gathers the data I need, but I just do not know how to group it to gather the result I need. How should I do that?

Comment: Is this Linq-to-SQL / to Entities? If so, use navigation properties, no joins.

Comment: @GertArnold, can you give me an example? For instance, how should I reach the TblFilterProd element set of a TblFilterSum element via navigation properties?

Comment: @GertArnold, the thing is, that there is no foreign key from tblFilterProdsInSum, just the values and currently table schema change is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution in lack of knowledge about LINQ group bys:

```
            Dim elements = (From filterSum In dataContext.GetTable(Of TblFilterSum)
                            Join filterProdInSum In dataContext.GetTable(Of TblFilterProdsInSum)
                        On filterSum.SumID Equals filterProdInSum.SumID
                            Join filterProd In dataContext.GetTable(Of TblFilterProd)
                        On filterProdInSum.ProdID Equals filterProd.ProdID
                            Join filterElementInProd In dataContext.GetTable(Of TblFilterElementsInProd)
                        On filterProd.ProdID Equals filterElementInProd.ProdID
                            Join filterElement In dataContext.GetTable(Of TblFilterElement)
                        On filterElementInProd.ElementID Equals filterElement.ElementID
                            Where sumIDs.Contains(filterSum.SumID)).Select(Function(r) New With {.SumID = r.filterSum.SumID, .ProdID = r.filterProd.ProdID, .filterElement = r.filterElement}).ToList
            'Dim results As New List(Of TTPair(Of Integer, List(Of TTPair(Of Integer, List(Of TblFilterElement)))))
            Dim results As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of TblFilterElement)))
            For Each element In elements
                If (Not results.ContainsKey(element.SumID)) Then
                    results.Item(element.SumID) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of TblFilterElement))
                End If
                If (Not results.Item(element.SumID).ContainsKey(element.ProdID)) Then
                    results.Item(element.SumID).Item(element.ProdID) = New List(Of TblFilterElement)
                End If
                results.Item(element.SumID).Item(element.ProdID).Add(element.filterElement)
            Next
```

Explanation:

I added a `Select` to have objects containing `SumID`, `ProdID` and `filerElement`. Then created a Dictionary and when I iterated elements, checked whether the key of `SumID` exists. If not, I created it. Then checked whether there is an element with `ProdID` key inside the element with the key of `SumID` exists. If not, I created it. Then I added `filterElement` to the `List`.